# Can I install Windows 7 64 bit on VirtualBox running on a Windows 7 32 bit OS?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtualbox

Is it possible to install Windows 7 64 bit on VirtualBox running on Windows 7 32 bit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VirtualBox versions 2.1+ support 64 bit guests inside 32 bit hosts, assuming the following is true:

> 1. You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see
>      chapter
>      1.2, Software vs. hardware virtualization (VT-x and AMD-V), page
>      11).
> 2. You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM
>      for which you want 64-bit support;
>      software virtualization is not
>      supported for 64-bit VMs.
> 3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating
>      system, you must also select a 64-bit
>      operating system for the particular
>      VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit
>      hosts incurs additional overhead,
>      VirtualBox only enables this support
>      upon explicit request.

From. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests

Hosting a Windows guest inside a Windows host shouldn't be a problem, so as long as you pass the three points, it should work.

Comment: aww that is why it didnt run. Its 64 bit but no VT