# Run a 64-bit virtual machine on windows 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, 64-bit, virtual-machine, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I Install Windows 7 64 bit on VirtualBox running on Windows 7 32 bit OS ?](https://superuser.com/questions/144539/can-i-install-windows-7-64-bit-on-virtualbox-running-on-windows-7-32-bit-os)

Hello,

I have a PC with a 64 bit processor, but I have Windows 32 bit as operative system. I want to create a virtual machine to install Windows 7 64 bits. I've created a viirtual machine with virtual PC but I can't configure as 64 bit machine on a 32 bit machine. I have VMWare as wll installed, but I don't know where exactly I can change from 32bit to 64 bit the virtual machine.

Is it possible to run a 64 bit machine on a windows 32 bit machine running on a 64 bit machine? 
Should I use other software for the virtualization? 
If I can do with VMWare where can I set the machine as 64bit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have installed a 32 bit OS on a 64 bit system, your processor might support running 64 bit guest OS'es. Also check out the official VMware CPU compatibility tool: http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/processor_check_5_5_dt/dCpiQGhkYmRAZQ== to see if your CPU supports running 64 bit guests.

From the compatibility check guide:
http://www.vmware.com/pdf/processor_check.pdf

> VMware Workstation version 5.5
>   supports virtual machines with 64-bit
>   guest operating systems, running on
>   host machines with the following
>   processors:
>   • AMD™ Athlon™ 64,
>   revision D or later
>   • AMD Opteron™,
>   revision E or later
>   • AMD Turion™
>   64, revision E or later
>   • AMD
>   Sempron™, 64-bit-capable revision D or
>   later (experimental support)
>   • Intel™ EM64T VT-capable processors
>   (experimental support)

It is, however, important to note that you can not install a 64 bit OS on a 32 bit system.

Comment: I think you mean you can't have a 64 bit client OS on a 32 bit system.

Comment: @oKtosiTe Haha of course! Thanks for noticing my stupidity! ;)

Comment: but where can I change the processor from 32bit to 64bit in VMWare? In the processor I can choose Automatic, 'Automatic with replay', 'Binary translation', 'Intel VT-X or AMD-V' and 'Intel VT-X/EPT or AMD-V/RVI'. How can I mark the processor as 64 bit or is any of these of this type?

Comment: @BloodPhilia: Stupidity is too strong of a word. :-)

Comment: @Juanillo unless you have a compatible CPU in your host system, you will not be able to select a CPU with 64 bit capabilities for your guest OS. So all the selectable CPU's will be 32 bit.

Comment: @BloodPhilia I've downloaded the utility and it says my hadware is compatible. The problem now is that I don't know how to set the option of 64bit in the virtual machine

Comment: @Juanillo In that case, with the VM creation wizard, select that you want to install a 64 bit operating system. (E.g. "Windows Server 2008 x64 Edition") Make sure the CPU is then set to "Automatic" and install the 64 bit guest OS. You'll then be running a 64 bit system. http://virtualization.sysprobs.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/64bitOS.png

Comment: Like BloodPhilia said... Use VMWare Player or Workstation for this, I've had this working fine.

Comment: @BloodPhilia sorry, this is not correct, you can install 64-bit VM on a 32-bit OS, provided you have a 64-bit CPU & VT-x support, refer to my dupe question link

Comment: Hmm, your first sentence confused me a bit, @Blood, edited to make it a bit clear.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124/can-i-run-a-64-bit-vmware-image-on-a-32-bit-machine The first answer answers your bit about 64 on 32 on 64.