# Can I run a Windows 8 64-bit VM on a Windows 7 32-bit VirtualBox host?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8-preview

I have a laptop with a 64-bit processor running Windows 7 32-bit.

Is it possible to install Windows 8 64-bit via VirtualBox on this configuration? Which version of VirtualBox do I have to download?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install Windows 7 64 bit on VirtualBox running on a Windows 7 32 bit OS?](http://superuser.com/questions/144539/can-i-install-windows-7-64-bit-on-virtualbox-running-on-a-windows-7-32-bit-os)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you VirtualBox can run a 64 bit guest on a 32 bit host OS, with some conditions, see the [Virtual Box FAQ](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests), quoted below:

> VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit
>   host operating systems,[11] provided that the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> - You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support
>     (see the section called “Hardware vs. software virtualization”).
> - You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for
>     which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not
>     supported for 64-bit VMs.
> - If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating
>     system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the
>     particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs
>     additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon
>     explicit request.